# Mi aplicación tipo Windows Form de VB.Net compila bien, pero muestra unos mensajes ¿Cómo puedo resolverlos para que ya no salgan?

Tags: vb.net

Aunque una vez que compila y lo ejecuto corre bien, sin problemas. Esos mensajes que muestra parecen no interferir, pero salen por algo que no entiendo bien. ¿Qué me sugieren para tratar de arreglar lo que está diciendo de manera que ya no salgan? (es algo relacionado con WMPLib).

**ADJUNTO LOS MENSAJES QUE VISUALIZA DURANTE LA COMPILACIÓN:**

> Operación Compilar iniciada..
>
> 1>------ Operación Compilar iniciada: proyecto: Reproductor, configuración: Release Any CPU ------
>
> 1>  La referencia COM 'WMPLib' es el ensamblado de interoperabilidad del control ActiveX 'AxWMPLib' pero estaba marcada para su vinculación por el compilador con la marca /link. Esta referencia COM se tratará como una referencia y no se vinculará.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2827,5): warning MSB3305: Procesando la referencia COM "WMPLib" desde la ruta de acceso "C:\WINDOWS\system32\wmp.dll". El importador de la biblioteca de tipos detectó una función getter de propiedad 'sessionPlaylistCount' en el tipo 'WMPLib.IWMPNowPlayingHelperDispatch' sin un tipo de valor devuelto válido. El importador intentará importar esta propiedad como un método.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2827,5): warning MSB3305: Procesando la referencia COM "WMPLib" desde la ruta de acceso "C:\WINDOWS\system32\wmp.dll". El contador de referencias en tiempo de ejecución no puede calcular las referencias de al menos uno de los argumentos para 'IWMPGraphEventHandler.NotifyAcquireCredentials'. Estos argumentos se pasarán como puntero y puede que requieran código no seguro para la manipulación.
>
> 1>  Reproductor -> D:\Reproductor v1.0\Reproductor\bin\Release\Reproductor v1.0.exe
>
> ========== Compilar: 1 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========

Comment: Todas las advertencias son problemas, no necesariamente graves. Puedes omitirlas, pero lo mejor es tratarlas. Según lo que comentan [en este foro](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?696593-Warnings-after-compiling) no es algo que puedas solucionar. El problema es de .NET procesando una librería COM. Así que puedes optar por ignorarlo o investigar más al respecto. Siempre es útil tener la lista de errores para informarte sobre alguno que no entiendas, como [este](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb3305).

Comment: Ah, OK. Gracias por el comentario y gracias por la info de los enlaces.